# Eating faux-Matza Before Pesach

Tags: minhag, chametz-leaven, eating, matzah, nissan

[Mishna Berura 471:2:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=159) says there are those that do not eat Matza starting Rosh Chodesh Nissan. May one eat Matza that is Chometz?

Comment: Why would it be any different than matzah ashirah (see M.B. :10)?

Comment: Plain Chometz Matza is not made from anything other than flour and water. The only difference is that it may take longer than 18 minutes. It also tastes very similar to Kosher L'Pesach machine Matza. However Matza Ashira has juice in it and tastes significantly different.

Comment: @Alex, bc Matzah 'Ashirah is not _necessarily_ Hametz Gamur (hence you can feed it to the very young and infirm). Although, Gershon, how exactly would one have Matzah that is Hametz? If it is Hametz, it is by definition not Matzah, even if it looks like Matzah. It's just a cracker. If you are talking about Matzah that has become contaminated by close contact with actual Hametz, then I agree you have a good question, but I would imagine the Minhag holds. I will leave it to others to post a clearer answer, but can you clarify your intent in the question?

Comment: @GershonGold, I just read your comment. I think my above comment is true, and your case is not really Matzah, just a cracker.

Comment: The Matza that is sold all year, as far as I know is Hamotzi and is not considered a cracker.

Comment: @GershonGold, they may not be regarded as crackers for purposes of the Berachah (according to Ashkenazim), but that does not mean that they are Matzah LeHalachah. According to (some?) Sepharadim, even Halachic Matzah is Mezonoth throughout the rest of the year, because it is, um, a cracker and not bread.

Comment: The true Sephardi matzos look like some sort of pita, not like Ashkenazi ones.

Comment: @DoubleAA and Gershon, I'd rather know about contaminated Matzah (as faux-Matzah seems rather obvious to me).

Comment: @GershonGold Re: "The true Sephardi matzos look like some sort of pita, not like Ashkenazi ones" many (most?) Sepharadim eat Ashkenazi/cracker-like Matzoth for פסח and say Hamotzi on פסח when they do so. The rest of year they say Mezonoth.

Comment: @SethJ It probably depends on how ikkar hadin you view the contaminated matza as assur, similar to the cases in [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15263/759).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [OC 471 sk 12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=159), the Mishna Berurah mentions that certain types of matza which we are only machmir to treat as chametz (eg matza that folded over itself in the oven) are forbidden to be eaten on Erev Pesach as they are actually kosher matza according to the basic law. The assumption of this point is that had they actually been chametz, they would have been permitted despite tasting exactly like matza. So your chametz-crackers are permitted.

EDIT: In his footnotes to the Mishna Berura (published as ביצחק יקרא), [Rav Nevenzhal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avigdor_Nebenzahl) says that the matza sold year round as chametz should not be eaten on Erev Pesach even before the fourth hour as it might actually be kosher matza and therefore forbbidden. He does not mention if this chumra (that it might not be chametz) applies going back to Rosh Chodesh, or only on Erev Pesach when the possible prohibition is rabbinic in nature.

Comment: "So your chametz-crackers are permitted." +1

Comment: @SethJ "So your chametz-matza is permitted" was just too weird to say!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15262/not-eating-matza-from-rosh-chodesh-nissan/15263#comment29845_15262

Comment: @SethJ ברוך שכיוונתי