# Egg matzah in early Nisan

Tags: minhag, passover, matzah, nissan

This shabbos, my LOR announced that the shul was done being kashered for Pesach, and so kiddush would be pesadich. To fulfill the need for mezonot, he had brought in egg matzah, saying that egg matzah is not considered matzah and therefore acceptable to eat by those who keep the minhag of not eating matzah from Rosh Chodesh Nisan until Pesach. Does everybody agree that egg matzah is acceptable for people who keep that minhag?

I would imagine that even among Ashkenazim who generally do not eat egg matzah at all on Pesach, many poskim might say that one should still not eat it leading up to Pesach.

Comment: I asked a Breslaver Rov in LA this a couple weeks ago, and he informed me that it would not be an issue, since Matza Ashira is not suitable for the Matzos at the Seder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [quote myself](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/matzah-meal-before/15537#15537):

> The Mishna Berura ([OC 471 sk 10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=159)) points out that one may eat Matza Ashira (eg. Egg Matza) on Erev Pesach because one cannot fulfill his obligation to eat matza on seder night with it. Seemingly the only things that are forbidden to eat are those with which one can fulfill his obligation to eat matza.